# Skip Input image in email for some template using html and apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

**i use this code for different email template**

else if (inputSheet.initialadvice == "Training Visa"){
var emailtemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Training Visa");
var subject ="[DRAFT] "+inputSheet.engagement+" - HK - "+inputSheet.lastname+", "+inputSheet.firstname+" - Training Visa Application - Initiation";
var myimage = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder id').getFilesByName(`training.png`).next().getBlob();

else if (inputSheet.initialadvice == "Extension"){
var emailtemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Extension");
var subject ="[DRAFT] "+inputSheet.engagement+" - HK - "+inputSheet.lastname+", "+inputSheet.firstname+" - Extension Application - Initiation";

**this is the code for email draft**

```
inputSheet.caseworkerEmail,
//"haikal.wan.rosni@vialto.com",
subject,
"",
{from:alias,
to:me,
cc:,caseworkeremail,
htmlBody:emailtemphtml,
inlineImages:
{pngimage: myimage},
name:"mailbox",})
```

i need to skip insert image on extension template email, but then it cannot be run if i skip the var myimage in Extension code.

Comment: Code was not proper formatted

Comment: @AmanGojariya which code ya